# How to set Text direction of chart to rotate all text 270 using poi?

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi

In the excel, here's what I expect, as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeR2M.png)

In the excel, there is a data labels on the chart, the values displayed default to horizontal, I can set text direction to rotate all text 270 in the text options of format data labels. but, I don't know how to implement this in code with apache poi? Could anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
    XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 27, 5);
    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

    XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setTitle("Week");
    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setTitle("Face Amount ($MM)");
    leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
    leftAxis.setMaximum(10000);

    XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange((XSSFSheet) sheet,
            new CellRangeAddress(299, 299, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange((XSSFSheet) sheet,
            new CellRangeAddress(300, 300, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

    XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
    XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys);
    series1.setTitle("2x", null);

    chart.plot(data);

    XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
    bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
    bar.setGapWidth(3);
    bar.setBarGrouping(BarGrouping.STACKED);

    //set data labels
    XSSFChart xssfChart = (XSSFChart) chart;
    CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
    CTBoolean ctBool = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
    ctBool.setVal(true);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls().setShowVal(ctBool);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLeaderLines();
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowLeaderLines(ctBool);
    ctBool.setVal(false);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowSerName(ctBool);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowPercent(ctBool);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowLegendKey(ctBool);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowCatName(ctBool);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowLeaderLines(ctBool);
    plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowBubbleSize(ctBool);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the picture does not show.

Comment: Please show the code where you are creating the bar chart using `apache poi` or do at least providing a link to the example code you are using. Also please show the code which sets the default horizontal data labels. Since your question is how to  deviate from defaults you at least must be able creating the defaults first.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for your reminding, I have added code.

Answer (score 0):

As your code shows, you are setting the data labels using the underlying low level beans of `apache poi`.

But how can one working with those? There is no documentation about `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes public available. So we need downloading the sources of `ooxml-schemas` from [maven](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) for example. Then we can use `javadoc` to create a `API` documentation. Now we can look how to create and use the classes.

But also we need the meanings of the `XML` elements and attributes, the classes are creating. For this one could study the `Office Open XML` specifications. But my preferred method is to create a simple `*.xlsx` file having the needed settings using `Excel`'s `GUI`. Then unzip that `*.xlsx` file and have a look at the `XML` in the  `*.xml` files stored in that `ZIP` archive. For the first chart this is `/xl/charts/chart1.xml`.

Doing this we will find:

```
<c:dLbls>
 <c:txPr>
  <a:bodyPr rot="-5400000"/>
  <a:p><a:pPr><a:defRPr/></a:pPr></a:p>
 </c:txPr>
 ...
</c:dLbls>
```

for data labels when text rotation is set.

That is a `txPr` (text properties) element in `dLbls` having a `bodyPr` (body properties)  element having a `rot` attribute set. Value of the `rot` attribute  is rotation angle * 60000. The -5400000 for example is -90.00 * 60000. Also there is a `p` (paragraph) element having a `pPr` (paragraph properties) element having a `defRPr` (default run properties) to set that the data label text runs have default properties.

Putting all together the code used in `apache poi` for this would be:

```
...
// text properties having rotation set
plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewTxPr()
 .addNewBodyPr().setRot((int)(-90.00 * 60000));
// paragraph properties having default run properties set
plotArea.getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getTxPr()
 .addNewP().addNewPPr().addNewDefRPr();
...
```

where `plotArea` is `CTPlotArea` as in your code. And the first series must have `dLbls` set using `addNewDLbls` as you done in your code.